# Popup Window not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a window pop up when the "popup" button is pressed as a part of my Javascript assignment for school but can't figure out why my code isn't working. I've assigned the popup button to a jQuery selector and it still will not open.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Adam Ginther's Pop-up Window</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
Congrats! You won!
</div>
<div id="centreblock">
<h1>WOW! AMAZING!!!</h1>
<img src="images/ipad.gif" width="100%" height="250">
<p>Congratulations! You won a free iPad! Enter your name, address, and phone number to have it delivered now.
<form action="">
<br>
<label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="firstName" name="firstName">
<br>
<br>
<label for ="lastName">Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" size"12" id="lastName" name="lastName">
<br>
<br>
<label for="address">Address: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="address" name="address">
<br>
<br>
<label for="phoneNum">Phone Number: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="phoneNum" name="phoneNum">
</form>
<br>
<a href="#" id="popup"><br>REDEEM THIS SPECTACULAR OFFER NOW!</a>
<br>
</div>
<script src="http//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


//script.js
var new_win;
var firstName;
var lastName;
var address;
var phoneNumber;

function newWindow() { 
    firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    if (firstName !='') {
    window.open('popup.html');
    } else {
        $('#firstName').addClass('error');
    };
    $(function() {
        $('#popup').click(function() {
            newWindow();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You've defined a function that is only invoked from within itself. There's no code to actually call the function in the first place. Remove the jquery domready code from within the function definition so it can actually get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Adam Ginther's Pop-up Window</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">


//script.js
var new_win;
var firstName;
var lastName;
var address;
var phoneNumber;

function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

function newWindow() { 
    firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    if (firstName !='') {
    popitup('popup.html');
    } else {
        $('#firstName').addClass('error');
    };
};

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#popup').click(function() {
            newWindow();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
Congrats! You won!
</div>
<div id="centreblock">
<h1>WOW! AMAZING!!!</h1>
<img src="images/ipad.gif" width="100%" height="250">
<p>Congratulations! You won a free iPad! Enter your name, address, and phone number to have it delivered now.
<form action="">
<br>
<label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="firstName" name="firstName">
<br>
<br>
<label for ="lastName">Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" size"12" id="lastName" name="lastName">
<br>
<br>
<label for="address">Address: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="address" name="address">
<br>
<br>
<label for="phoneNum">Phone Number: </label>
<input type="text" size="12" id="phoneNum" name="phoneNum">
</form>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="popup"><br>REDEEM THIS SPECTACULAR OFFER NOW!</a>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please note:

- The jquery version was outdated
- there are some changes done in the javascript function

I hope this might help. You can edit as per your flow and requirement.